# Article recommendation dataset

Tags: dataset, recommender-system

I am experimenting with a recommendation systems for articles (news, magazines etc). Is there any dataset available for the same which includes the demographic information of users as well?

I am actually trying to incorporate demographic information as well in recommending, hence looking for such a dataset. I really don't want to simulate such data as I think real data would give much more interesting insights than simulated one. Anyone aware of such?

I found one http://contest.plista.com/ but unfortunately its has german dataset and demographic information seems to be missing. There is Yahoo Front Page but its only for academic research. Would appreciate any information here.

Comment: Can anybody atleast tell that why is this off topic ? Its REALLY very rude to close this off without suggesting the appropriate place for this.

Comment: Regarding your comment: [What is a good place for “how/where do I get data on X” questions?](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/1298/10525), [What's wrong with this question about datasets?](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/1425/10525).

Comment: If you found anything about a dataset where users vote articles, I would also like to know